# Weird Behavior of Notebook Creation with Module?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, debugging

Compare the following two codes:

```
Module[{nb},
 nb = NotebookPut[];
 SetOptions[nb, NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "1"} :> NotebookWrite[nb, "1"]}]
 ]
```

and

```
nb = NotebookPut[];
SetOptions[nb, NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "1"} :> NotebookWrite[nb, "1"]}]
```

The only difference is the `Module` enclosing the code. But in the notebook generated by the first piece of code, one can't enter `1`, while in the second, one can.

I have no idea why this will happen, a simple `Trace` showed me that `Module` worked fine and generate some piece of code like:

```
nb$53460 = NotebookPut[];
SetOptions[nb$53460, NotebookEventActions :> {{"KeyDown", "1"} :> NotebookWrite[nb$53460, "1"]}]
```

which can, obviously, evaluate to a correct result.

What's happening behind the scene that makes the first piece of code run in an undisired way?

Comment: `nb` is out of scope when using `Module` or `Block`

Comment: change the action to `{"KeyDown", "1"} :> (If[OwnValues[nb] == {}, Print["outof scope"]]; NotebookWrite[nb, "1"])`, and you will find a difference of the two cases when pressing 1.

Comment: @FredSimons yes, this simple addition works! could you write this as an answer so that I can properly upvote it?

Comment: My additional guess is that Out is assigned to Hold@nb so Kernel decides to not forget about that yet. P.s. do not use global nb either, it will break as soon as the kernel quits. Put there NotebookWrite[EvaluationNotebook...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of a `Module` is a list of variables that will be local to the evaluation of the second argument of `Module`. `Module` uses *lexical scoping*: for each of the variables a special kernel variable, with a \$ sign and the module number, is created.

```
Module[{x}, Information[x]]

(* Global`x$2293
   Attributes[x$2293]={Temporary} *)
```

These special kernel variables have attribute `Temporary`, which means that they are removed when the `Module` has been evaluated and they are not needed anymore, as in the situation above:

```
Names["x$*"]

(* {} *)
```

However, it might happen that the result of the evaluation of the `Module` is an expression in which the name of a local variable turns up. Then of course the name of that variable is not removed. This is a simple example:

```
Module[{x=5}, Hold[x]] 

(* Hold[x$2303] *)

x$2303

(* 5 *)
```

Now let us have a look at your first example.

```
Module[{nb},nb=CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{n=0},InputField[Dynamic@n]]];
  SetOptions[nb,NotebookEventActions:>{"KeyDown","1"}:>NotebookWrite[nb,"1"]}]]
```

Evaluation of this `Module` gives `Null`. That means that the local name for `nb` is removed as soon as the `Dialog` notebook with its options has been created. When we press the key `1`, nothing can be written to `nb` since `nb` does not exist.

We can prevent the removal of the local name by letting it leak out of the `Module`, for example as we have done it in the second example:

```
Module[{nb},nb=CreateDialog[DynamicModule[{n=0},InputField[Dynamic@n]]];
  SetOptions[nb,NotebookEventActions:>{{"KeyDown","1"}:>NotebookWrite[nb,"1"]}];
  Hold[nb]];
```

Now assigning to the local variable `nb` is possible. Observe that the output of the `Module` is suppressed by using the semicolon. The output is still in the kernel:

```
%

(* Hold[nb$2448] *)
```

Therefore, the local name is not removed.

**Addendum**

When you indeed want to leak a local variable of a `Module` out of the `Module`, it is simpler to construct that variable explicitely with the function `Unique`. Just as `Module`, it adds a \$ sign and a number to the name, and that number will not be used again in the same kernel session. In fact, it is the module number `$ModuleNumber`.

```
$ModuleNumber
(* 2367 *)

Unique[a]
(* a$2368 *)
```

So in the first example:

```
With[{nb=Unique[nb]},nb=NotebookPut[];
  SetOptions[nb,NotebookEventActions:> {"KeyDown","1"}:>NotebookWrite[nb,"100"]}]]

Names["nb$*"]
(* {"nb$2370"} *)
```